PowerShell list virtual directories inside azure storage account
The below PowerShell script provides directory details filtered with directory name "internal" and tag name " Business" also with container name "landing", I noticed few storage accounts with project directories inside directory "internal" and trying to list them all in the output.
I tested adding -prefix internal to $directories variable but this is not giving me desired result.
I need to list all directories inside a parent directory named internal under container landing.
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx' -UseDeviceAuthentication
# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the tag key to filter by
$tagKey = "Business"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
# Set the current subscription context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

# Get all storage accounts in the current subscription
$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }

foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
    # Get the metrics for the storage account
    $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
    $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"

    try {
        $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
        $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }

        if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
            $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
        } else {
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve metrics for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $averageCapacity = 0
    }

    $ctx = $storageAccount.Context
    $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "landing" }
    foreach ($container in $containers) {
    $prefix = "internal"
      $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Prefix "internal" -Container $container.Name -Context $ctx
     
      $directories = $blobs |  ForEach-Object {
            $parts = $_.Name.Split('/')
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $parts.Length - 1; $i++) {
                $parts[0..$i] -join '/'
            }
        } | Sort-Object -Unique

      $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
        #SubscriptionId       = $subscription.Id
        SubscriptionName     = $subscription.Name
        ResourceGroup        = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
        StorageAccount       = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
        ContainerName        = $container.Name
        UsedCapacityInBytes  = $averageCapacity
        TagName              = $tagKey
        TagValue             = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
        Directories          = $directories -join ", "
       
    }
  }
}
   # Output the results
   $results | Format-Table -AutoSize




I noticed few storage accounts with project directories inside directory "internal" and trying to list them all in the output.

In my environment, I have directory with subdirectories like zoom/recording/BBS/2024-8-7 in my Azure Storage account.
Portal:

You can use the below script to get the storage account details (filtered by tags), storage account size, container(filtered by specific container) ,Particular directory and their subdirectory from the filtered containers.
Script:
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx' -UseDeviceAuthentication

# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the tag key to filter by
$tagKey = "createdby"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    # Set the current subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all storage accounts in the current subscription
    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }

    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        # Get the metrics for the storage account
        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"

        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }

            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
            } else {
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve metrics for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }

        $ctx = $storageAccount.Context
        $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "test" }

       foreach ($container in $containers) {
          $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $ctx | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "zoom/*" }

          # Extract unique directories within the "zoom" directory
          $directories = $blobs | ForEach-Object {
                $parts = $_.Name.Split('/')
                for ($i = 0; $i -lt $parts.Length - 1; $i++) {
                    $parts[0..$i] -join '/'
                }
            } | Sort-Object -Unique

          $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName     = $subscription.Name
            ResourceGroup        = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
            StorageAccount       = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            ContainerName        = $container.Name
            UsedCapacityInBytes  = $averageCapacity
            TagName              = $tagKey
            TagValue             = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
            Directories          = $directories -join ", "
            }
        }
    }
}

# Output the results
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize 

Output:
SubscriptionName                      ResourceGroup StorageAccount ContainerName UsedCapacityInBytes TagName   TagValue Directories                                                          
----------------                      ------------- -------------- ------------- ------------------- -------   -------- -----------                                                          
xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat891      test                     45155865 createdby venkat   zoom, zoom/recording, zoom/recording/BBS, zoom/recording/BBS/2024-8-7



I modified based on your above script and created same folder structure but the output directories is listing only "zoom" folder. Also I have to avoid listing all the files and folders inside, for example in "test" container I have to list child directories only from "zoom" directory. In my case the content in folder "zoom" is project directories and that is the final output I'm looking for.

The above script only list the folders  inside from root directory of zoom only

Have you tried with above code?

for example in "test" container I have to list child directories only from "zoom" directory. In my case the content in folder "zoom" is project directories and that is the final output I'm looking for. this is exactly script is doing.

Yes I tested the same code, not sure how to upload a screenshot image.

Can you share link of image?

https://www.imghippo.com/i/dreUs1723214825.jpg
https://www.imghippo.com/i/CsoES1723214861.png (In this storage account Landing is container name and Internal is root directory, inside internal root directory I have multiple test project folder created which need to be listed.

In the project1 folders is there any files?

In my environment I created with same folder and used the same code it executed successfully. https://i.imgur.com/Am8zjx1.png and output: https://i.imgur.com/deRzYBQ.png

In your output there is no used capacity value also can recheck the script and try once? @sudhirkaramchand

Took some time to get back on this. Yes the solution worked and giving me correct output, not sure what was the previous error though. Thank you for your assistance.

I have a some query with regards to the same script and raise a new question, wish you could look into this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78897364/azure-powershell-function-not-uploading-the-output-csv-to-blob-storage
