Azure PowerShell function not uploading the output .csv to blob storage
I have this Azure TimeTrigger function that has to fetch all the storage accounts with size based on tag filter and store that output to Azure blob storage account.
When I test run the function, it neither gives me any data but uploads the empty .csv file to blob or give any error in the job run. The script to fetch storage account details works fine but doesn't upload the data to .csv which is initially stored locally as "Source -C:\home\site\wwwroot\strgacctmp\strgaccsize20240821.csv" and then upload to blob storage. Kindly note, I am maintaining all the environment variables in the function.
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($GtStgAcc)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()

#SPN login to upload file. This need to read from Env variable
$tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
$thumb = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_THUMBID')
$appId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPID')
$appName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPNAME')
Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to call UC API"


# Get all subscriptions
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb - 
ApplicationId $appId
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the tag key to filter by
$tagKey = "CyberDefence"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$strg = @()

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    # Set the current subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all storage accounts in the current subscription
    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) 
    }

    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        # Get the metrics for the storage account
        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"

        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }

            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
            }
            else {
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve metrics for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }

        $ctx = $storageAccount.Context
        $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "landing" }

        foreach ($container in $containers) {
            $blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $ctx | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "internal/*" }

            # Extract unique directories within the "internal" directory
            $directories = $blobs | ForEach-Object {
                $parts = $_.Name.Split('/')
                for ($i = 0; $i -lt $parts.Length - 1; $i++) {
                    $parts[0..$i] -join '/'
                }
            } | Sort-Object -Unique

            $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
                SubscriptionName    = $subscription.Name
                ResourceGroup       = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                StorageAccount      = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
                ContainerName       = $container.Name
                UsedCapacityInBytes = $averageCapacity
                TagName             = $tagKey
                TagValue            = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
                Directories         = $directories -join ", "
            }
           
            $strg += $results  
        }
    }
}

#$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
Write-Host "Completed fetching storage account details"
#==================FunctionEnds=================

# Create folder to store source path 
$localPath = "$(Get-Location)\strgacctmp"
If (Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Write-Host "Folder already Exists!"
}
else {
    New-Item -Path "$localPath" -ItemType 'Directory' -Name strgacctmp -Force - ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "New Folder unitycatalogtemp Created!"
}


function uploadFileToBlob {
    Param(
        [String] $LocalFilePath,
        [String] $TargetFileName
    )
    $tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
    $storage_account = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT')
    $subscription = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME')
    $filesystemName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME')
    $destPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_FOLDER_PATH_UC_DASHBOARD')
    Write-Host " ----Retrieved App Settings from Function App--- "
    Write-Host "ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT - $storage_account"
    Write-Host "ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME - $subscription"
    Write-Host "ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME - $filesystemName"
    Write-Host "Source -$LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "destination Path -$destPath"
    Write-Host "Path from where files will be uploaded :$LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "-------------------------"
    Write-Host "selecting subscription: $subscription"

    #SPN login to upload file. This need to read from Env variable

    $thumb = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_THUMBID')
    $appId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPID')
    $appName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPNAME')
    Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to call UC API"

    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb -ApplicationId $appId
    Update-AzConfig -DefaultSubscriptionForLogin $subscription

    Write-Host "Update-AzConfig Successful for Subscription - $subscription"

    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_account -UseConnectedAccount -ErrorAction Stop
    

    try {
        $destPath += "/" + $TargetFileName
        New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $destPath -Source $LocalFilePath -ErrorAction Stop -Force
        Start-Sleep -seconds 2

        # Will execute on successful completion of folder upload
        Write-Host "File uploaded successfully!"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output " Error occured as below"
        $_
        exit
    }

}


$current_date = Get-Date -Format FileDate
Write-Host "Storage account details-"

# Export to CSV        
$CsvPath = $localPath + "\strgaccsize$current_date.csv"
$strg | Export-Csv -Path $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation

#Upload to blob
$targetFileName = "strgaccsize$($current_date).csv"
uploadFileToBlob -LocalFilePath $CsvPath -TargetFileName $targetFileName


#Need to delete locally stored files in folder unitycatalogtmp
Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Filter *.csv | Remove-Item -Recurse


The file is probably empty.  You need to debug code and find out why the $LocalFilePath is empty.

@jdweng yes the file is empty, not sure what I'm missing.

What is $subscriptions.  Is the count zero : $subscriptions.Count

I have 100+ subscriptions and it is going to get all the storage account details based on tag filter.

If the file is empty you are never getting to the line $strg += $results.  You need to do some debugging to find out why you are not getting to the line.
